# TinyMCE 4.2.5 not compatible with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, tinymce-4

I'm having problems setting up TinyMCE with an existing setup of RequireJS. The bootstrap file (tinymce.dev.js, tinymce.js, tinymce.jquery.js, tinymce.jquery.dev.js) for TinyMCE 4.2.5 has its own **define** and **require** functions, which **overwrite** the ones supplied by RequireJS. I've tried commenting out the lines so that they don't overwrite the existing RequireJS functions, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also using tinymce in my project. You don't have to modify any of the script file. To make it work you have to *shim* the tinymce library hence it will be fully compatible with requirejs (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).
So in your requirejs config you should have something like that :

```
requirejs.config({
    ...
    baseUrl : 'your_lib_path',
    shim : {
        ...
        'tinyMCE': { exports: 'tinyMCE'} 
    },
    paths: {
        ...
        'tinyMCE': 'tinymce/tinymce' //path from the baseUrl to tinymce.js ("js" extension has to be ommited)  
    }
});
```